# Using com exposed .net core object from .net framework

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, com

I've downloaded Microsofts' example projects for exposing a .net core object to com (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com), which comes with code that shows it all working.

Given you register the resulting server com dll using standard regsvr32, are you supposed to be able to use this from a .net framework app (or any environment where such registered dlls could used)?

When I create an exact copy of their (working) client console app but using .net framework, the runtime complains about the class not being registered.

Comment: Yes, it should work fine. Class not registered (or 0x80040154 / REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) is exclusively a deployment /registration issue. Make sure you have registered your .NET Core COM object in the same registry (32b vs 64b) as your calling .NET Framework process (x86 vs x64).

Comment: I did register it using regsvr32, which was required to even get the .net core app to be able to activate it. However, the .net framework app (same code, and run from within the same solution) still complains about the class not being registered.

Comment: I understand that, but "class not registered" is *always* a deployment issue. Same solution is irrelevant. Make sure your .NET Framework app is running as 64bit if you register in 64bit registry. Compile as x64, or uncheck "Prefer 32-bit", etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying. You are correct in that if I force the .net framework app to run using x64 it works. I then unregistered the com dll (confirmed in that the .net core app then stopped working) and re-registered using \windows\syswow64\regsvr32, but running the x86 version of the .net framework app still does not work. Is their a route forward for this aspect?

Comment: Sorry, further connecting the dots I set all project involved to x86 and this works. What I'm trying to do next is use the .net core COM object directly from vb6 but ofc I cannot even reference the dlls. If I setup a .net framework client between the core and vb6 environments and expose that to COM it all works. If there a route forward for that?

Comment: This is another question. This is because .NET Core COM objects don't create .TLB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#additional-notes so you have to build one by yourself to use with VB6. (BTW this is a totally dumb design decision, maybe it'll change some day in the future)